# Logback with WildFly9 & Hibernate

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, logback

I am having trouble configuring logback with WildFly 9.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also added the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in my `WEB-INF` folder (also in my sub-projects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding 
            some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Whenever I run my application I see the default logs, as if logback isn't even loaded in the first place. (no warnings or errors that the logback config isn't found etc)

I've tried multiple threads but none have worked for me so far

[SLF4J + Logback does not log in WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079492/slf4j-logback-does-not-log-in-wildfly)

[Application specific logging in WildFly 9.0.1 FINAL (SL4J + Logback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337285/application-specific-logging-in-wildfly-9-0-1-final-sl4j-logback)

My logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>

        <appender name="SLACK" class="com.github.maricn.logback.SlackAppender">
            <!-- Slack API token -->
            <!-- <token>1111111111-1111111-11111111-111111111</token> -->
            <!-- Slack incoming webhook uri. Uncomment the lines below to use incoming webhook uri instead of API token. -->
            <webhookUri>xxxxxxx</webhookUri>
            <!-- Channel that you want to post - default is #general -->
            <channel>xxx</channel>
            <!-- Formatting (you can use Slack formatting - URL links, code formatting, etc.) -->
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %class - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
            <!-- Username of the messages sender -->
            <username>xxxx</username>
            <!-- Emoji to be used for messages -->
            <iconEmoji>:stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye:</iconEmoji>
        </appender>

        <!-- Currently recommended way of using Slack appender -->
        <appender name="ASYNC_SLACK" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
            <appender-ref ref="SLACK" />
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
            </filter>
        </appender>


  <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL" />
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_SLACK" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this an EAR deployment?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins WAR

Comment: The configuration you're using should mostly work as you expect. The one catch is that Hibernate will not log with your logback configuration, but instead use the logging subsystem on WildFly. You should be seeing any error messages from your application being logged via logback though.